# Team Fortress 2 Sounds

Tags: team-fortress-2

So I have a folder of weapon sounds from Team Fortress 2. Is there an easy way to match between the sounds and a weapon? Some are straightforward (such as wrench_hit_world) but others aren't clear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just looking at the sounds in `team fortress 2 content.gcf/tf/sound/weapons`, here are ones that aren't labeled with their common names or might be confusing:

- `axe` - Scotsman's Skullcutter, and probably the Headless Horsemann's Axe as well
- `bat_baseball` - Sandman
- `bat` - Normal bat
- `blade` - all spy knives
- `bow` - Huntsman
- `cbar` - Crowbar (not in TF2)
- `demo_charge` - Chargin' Targe
- `fist` - Heavy's fists
- `gatling` - Brass Beast
- `metal_gloves` - Fists of Steel
- `minifun` - Natasha
- `pickaxe` - Equalizer, but sounds like it could be the swing sounds for the other Soldier weapons as well
- `pipe_bomb` - stickies blowing up

Most of the others are pretty straightforward, e.g. `holy_mackerel`, `letranger`, `boxing_gloves`

Comment: That's a good start, what about things like the wrench hitting a player? All the wrench_hits seem to be for world/build hits.

Comment: @Jim, that might be the `cbar` sounds